# Oracle DDL Error - ORA 00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, ddl

This DDL query does not work and I cannot figure out why, would appreciate help from more experienced individuals :)

When I try running it in Oracle it returns the error message ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis

```
CREATE TABLE "Attendees" (
  "attendee_id" number(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  "attendee_name" varchar2(50),
  "attendee_class" number(4),
  "attendee_school" varchar2(50),
  "attendee_status" varchar2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE "History" (
  "history_id" number(4) PRIMARY KEY,
  "history_dt" date,
  "history_time" timestamp,
  "history_status" varchar2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE "Event" (
  "event_id" number(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  "event_name" varchar2(200),
  "event_location" varchar2(100),
  "event_size" number(4),
  "start_dt" date,
  "end_dt" date,
  "class_restriction" number(4),
  "school_restriction" varchar2(100),
  ---"booking_id" number(10) references Booking(booking_id)
 --- "reservation_id" number(3) references Reservation(reservation_id)
);

CREATE TABLE "Booking" (
  "booking_id" number(4) PRIMARY KEY,
  "booking_date" date,
  "booking_cost" number(8),
  "booking_status" varchar2(50),
  "history_id" number(4) references History(history_id),
  "event_id" number(10) references Event(event_id)
);

CREATE TABLE "Reservation" (
  "reservation_id" number(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  "event_id" references Event(event_id),
  "attendee_id" references Attendees(attendee_id),
  "reservation_status" varchar2(50)
);
```

Comment: if you see in Event table create script, you have additional comma at the end

Comment: @Gabriel . . . Learn to debug your code.  Run each create table separately, find the one with the error.  If you don't spot the error, comment out the columns and other declarations until you find the problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: You didn't post the code that threw the error you report. It seems you attempted a solution already, and after that didn't work either, you copied the code **with** the modifications you made. You commented out two rows in one of the `CREATE TABLE` statements, and the code exactly as you posted it throws an `Invalid identifier` error on the `"Event"` table, because you have a comma after the last column definition immediately followed by the closing parenthesis. The original error, on the same table, was because you were missing a comma after the penultimate column definition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - see my Comment above. In this case, the OP did try to comment out some of the columns - he just didn't do it quite right (not uncommon for beginners) which led to even more errors.

Comment: not uncommon for seniors either ;p I find these more obvious when using leading commas.